# org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException when querying the DB

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I'm working on my first webapp and I'll use hibernate.

I have :

- Hibernate 3.2.5
- JSF 2.1
- Netbeans 7.2 Rc1

What I'm trying to do is, have a form in my webapp where the user will enter their credentials and then I'll match them against what I have in my DB.

First step for that is getting the info though JSF ==> works fine.
Next step is to query the DB to check I have this user and the password is correct.

For this second step I have a problem.

Here is the code I'm calling :

```
public String checkUser() {
    /** 1° Query the database for active users with specified name. */
    session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    PAC_USERS queryUsr = new PAC_USERS();
    session.load(PAC_USERS.class, queryUsr);
    session.beginTransaction();
    queryUsr.setName(this.name);
    this.user = (PAC_USERS) session.get(PAC_USERS.class, queryUsr);
    session.close();
    return null;
    /** 2° verify password against the one stored in the DB. */
}
```

here is the hibernate mapping file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class catalog="pac" name="com.a3c.pac.jsf.beans.PAC_USERS" table="pac_users">
       <id column="id" name="id" type="integer">
           <generator class="identity"/>
       </id>
       <property column="name" name="name" type="string"/>
       <property column="password" name="password" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and here is the SQL statement for my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `pac_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

What I want is to query the PAC_USERS table for records with name provided through the web page.

The PAC_USERS.java class might also help, here it is :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.a3c.pac.jsf.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author Utilisateurs
 */
public class PAC_USERS implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private Boolean active = false;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Take care,
Marco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally not understanding the purpose of the session.load and the session.get together.  If you want to load the PAC_USERS object (I won't even get into that naming) by name then you'd just do (assuming name is unique):

```
session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
this.user = (PAC_USERS) session.createQuery( "select u from PAC_USERS u where u.name = :username" )
        .setParameter( "username", this.name )
        .uniqueResult();
session.close();
```

But, so many things could be done better here.  First, this would appear to be a prime example of an anti-pattern we call session-per-operation, specifically opening and closing a Session for each request of the database.  Perhaps its just the nature of this particular use-case, just be aware...

Next, this is a good candidate for @NaturalId (or `<natural-id/>`) mapping.  Starting in 4.1 Hibernate offers loading entities by natural-id as a first class citizen on-par with loading by id.  Assuming you had mapped name as a natural id, you could instead have done:

```
session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
this.user = (PAC_USERS) session.bySimpleNaturalId( PAC_USERS.class ).load( this.name );
session.close();
```

Finally, if all you do with this returned user is to validate their authentication credentials, you are much better off not returning the entity at all.  Either, select the password directly and verify:

```
session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
final String password = (String) session.createQuery( "select u.password from PAC_USERS where u.name = :username" )
        .setParameter( "username", this.name )
        .uniqueResult();
session.close();
```

Or just perform the validation in the query:

```
session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
final Long matches = (Long) session.createQuery( "select count(*) from PAC_USERS where u.name = :username and u.password = :pswd" )
        .setParameter( "username", this.name )
        .setParameter( "pswd", this.password )
        .uniqueResult();
// count should == 1...
session.close();
```

Comment: Sir, I agree with you on all counts :).

Comment: This is just a test development to verify how I can do some basic functions (as I'm just starting). I'll make sure to research this `<natural-id>` capacity and will gladly integrate your suggestions on the username verification. Thanks a lot for this very comprehensive answer, it works very well. Thanks again.